# Thinking about PMF as an instance of PDF

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, statistics

I'm having difficulties in thinking about the probability mass function (PMF) as a special case of the probability density function (PDF).

I understand that PMF's are used in discrete examples, but in the extreme, we could have a continuous distribution with small clusters or neighbourhoods around $\mathbb{Z}$ (to simulate the concentrated mass in a point in the discrete case) of infinite density.

Is the modelling of infinite density correct? Or should it be $0$ instead?
Am I missing anything or doing anything wrong?

If you happen to have suggestions of viewing this problem in other ways, do suggest them.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every real-valued random variable (regardless of being continuous or discrete) has a cumulative distribution function $F\left(x\right)$. A random variable's cumulative distribution function should satisfy $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F\left(x\right) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F\left(x\right) = 1$. It is also known that $F\left(x\right)$ can be obtained from the density $f\left(x\right)$ by $F\left(x\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$.

If we consider some discrete random variable $X$ with masses $\left\{p_{1}, p_{2}, \dots\right\}$, $\sum_{i}p_{i} = 1$ at respective support points $\left\{x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots\right\}$, it is evident that $F\left(x\right)$ will look like a non-decreasing [staircase function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staircase_function). So if we wanted to represent $X$ with a density function satisfying $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F\left(x\right) = 0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}F\left(x\right) = 1$ and $F\left(x\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$, what should $f\left(x\right)$ look like? The mathematical object we require is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta\left(x\right)$, which may be informally thought of as an 'infinite spike' at $x = 0$ which integrates to $1$. So to construct $f\left(x\right)$ for a discrete random variable, we can build it out of Dirac delta functions weighted by masses $\left\{p_{1}, p_{2}, \dots\right\}$ placed at the support points $\left\{x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots\right\}$. For example if there were $n$ support points, we would define $f\left(x\right)$ as
$$f\left(x\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}p_{i}\delta\left(x - x_{i}\right)$$
which agrees with what we already know about computing the cumulative distribution function for a discrete random variable:
$$\begin{align} F\left(x\right) &= \operatorname{Pr}\left(X \leq x\right) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{x}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}p_{i}\delta\left(t - x_{i}\right)dt \\
&= \sum_{i: x_{i} \leq x}p_{i}
\end{align}$$
To summarise, we can imagine the density function of a discrete random variable to be a mixture of Dirac delta functions.